# Как через .htaccess сделать редирект со страниц с цифрами на такие же без цифр?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать редирект для всех страниц, которые содержат цифры в начале последней части URL на такой же урл без цифр?

Пример:

```
/category/category2/10-page.html
/category/110-page.html
/210-page.html
```

перенаправить на:

```
/category/category2/page.html
/category/page.html
/page.html
```

Буду благодарен если кто подскажет решение через htaccess

Comment: Неужели решения нет?

Comment: Не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз.